# function calls between classes

Tags: java

Can anyone please tell me what r we actually meaning by the following statement (I encountered it in one of my tutorials)

```
String s1 = Utilities.gets1(UtilityConstants.MY_SEVICE_NAME);
```

I have found that `Utilities.java` , `UtilityConstants.java` files do exist in the project.

I know with this vague little information it is difficult for you to convey the proper meaning.

But can you please make clear what sort of call is that?

Comment: Honest, try to learn the language first. If you can't understand Java basics, you won't go too far on any task you are given.

Comment: and if people are *supposedly* helping you by answering your queries, the least you can do is to accept the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a method `gets1` in `Utilities` class, which accepts a [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) parameter and returns a `String`. The string parameter *happens* to be selected from another class `UtilityConstants`, which contains *at least* one `static` [which could also be `final`] string variable declaration having the name `MY_SEVICE_NAME`.

Answer (score 2):

Well it certainly *looks* like a call to a static method called `gets1` in the `Utilities` class, with an argument of `UtilityConstants.MY_SERVICE_NAME`.

In other words, the expression `UtilityConstanst.MY_SERVICE_NAME` is evaluated, and then that value is passed as an argument to `gets1`, where the corresponding parameter will start off with that value.

The return value of the method is a `String` reference - which could conceivably be a null reference. The value of `s1` will be the returned value. (Note that it's a reference, not a `String` object itself.)

If it *is* a static method (as opposed to the possible-but-unlikely situation where `Utilities` is an expression such as a variable), then no instance of the `Utilities` class is required to make the call; the `gets1` method won't have an implicit instance of `Utilities` to access.

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

From the `Utilities` class you are taking the name of a service identified by the `static` (and possibly `final`) field `MY_SEVICE_NAME`.

I said possibly because the field name is uppercase and `_` separated, this in java usually means that you are dealing with a `final` field.

Answer (score 0):

MY_SEVICE_NAME is static constant of UtilityConstants

gets1 is static method of Utilities class

you can read about static here -  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

In nutshell - **static** is not an instance variable/constant, it is a variable/constant of the class, you can always access it without class instance.